# Split integer into array VB

Tags: vb.net, arrays

Good afternoon,

How can i split a value and insert it into a array in VB?

**An example:**

The initial value is 987654321.

Using a for loop i need to insert the value as something like this:

Position(1) = 9 'The first number from the splited integer

Position(2) = 8 'The second number from the splited integer

and so on...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is untested:

```
Dim x As Integer = 987654321
Dim s As String = x.ToString
Dim a(s.Length) As String

For i As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
  a(i) = s.Substring(i, 1)
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
Dim number As Integer = 987654321
Dim strText As String = number.ToString()

Dim charArr() As Char = strText.ToCharArray()
```

Once the numbers are separated, you can then pull them out from this array and convert them back to numbers if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim number As Integer = 987654321
Dim digits() As Integer = number.ToString().Cast(Of Integer)().ToArray()
```

Comment: Getting an invalid cast exception when calling the `.Cast(of Integer)()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Will show any number separated in 3 different message box.
You can make a function with the example to better suit your purpose.

```
Sub GetNumber()
Dim x As Integer, s As String
x = 987
s = LTrim(Str(x))

For i = 1 To Len(s)
    MsgBox Mid(s, i, 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here is the most elegant solution I could get to work:

```vb
Dim key As Integer = 987654321
Dim digits() As Integer = System.Array.ConvertAll(Of Char, Integer)(key.ToString.ToCharArray, Function(c As Char) Integer.Parse(c.ToString))
```